# How can I optimize Google Analytics for GTmetrix?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, performance, google-tag-manager, optimization

I'm optimizing my website using GTmetrix and I've got good grades, but it's still not perfect.

Look at this image for PageSpeed:

[image: pagespeed image]

And this one for YSlow:

[image: yslow image]

The picture shows that my value is not perfect because I installed the Google Analytics script on my website. If I delete it, I can get a perfect score, but I need Google Analytics to analyze my website.

So how do I optimize the Google Analytics script on my website without removing it?

Answer (score 2):

It's a real pain that Google reccomends this on their own products. I have looked into doing this before and I have found a couple of solutions but nothing is perfect and i've found that having a 100/100 score doesn't really provide a worthwhile improvement over something like 80/100.

There are a few good sites i've found while researching whether I should do this myself.
Most sites I have looked at suggest one of the best options is to host the Google Analytics code locally.

https://www.keycdn.com/blog/leverage-browser-caching

https://technumero.com/leverage-browser-caching-google-analytics/

Comment: thanks. I will try that link. yesterday I had thought to host the Google Analytics code locally. but I am afraid if there is a change from the Google Analytics script. it does not update in the local

Comment: That will be an issue. Plus as far as I know there is no easy way to know when they've updated the code.

Comment: yes. from your link says to use cron job. maybe it is a solution